# Rails compass libraries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, compass-sass

I have installed compass via rubygems

doug:aggio davide$ sudo gem list compass

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

compass (0.10.0.pre2)
compass-colors (0.3.1)

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

fancy-buttons (0.3.7)

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

haml (2.2.16, 2.2.14, 2.2.13, 2.2.10, 2.2.9, 2.2.6, 2.2.4, 2.2.3, 2.2.2, 2.2.1, 2.2.0, 2.0.10, 2.0.9)
haml-edge (2.3.100, 2.3.97, 2.3.83, 2.3.67, 2.3.62, 2.3.43, 2.3.29, 2.3.27, 2.3.21, 2.1.56, 2.1.41, 2.1.8, 2.1.3)

Rails configurations

### compass.rb

```
require 'compass'
require 'compass-colors'
require 'fancy-buttons'


# If you have any compass plugins, require them here.
Compass.configuration.parse(File.join(RAILS_ROOT, "config", "compass.config"))
Compass.configuration do |config|
  config.project_path = RAILS_ROOT
  config.sass_dir = "app/stylesheets"
  config.css_dir = "public/stylesheets/compiled"
end

Compass.configuration.environment = RAILS_ENV.to_sym
Compass.configure_sass_plugin!
```

---

### compass.config

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.

project_type = :rails
project_path = RAILS_ROOT if defined?(RAILS_ROOT)
# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "public/stylesheets/compiled"
sass_dir = "app/stylesheets"
images_dir = "public/images"
javascripts_dir = "public/javascripts"

# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
# relative_assets = true
http_images_path = "/images"
http_stylesheets_path = "/stylesheets"
http_javascripts_path = "/javascripts"
```

### this is some information about compass:

```
doug:aggio davide$  ./script/runner "require 'pp'; pp Sass::Plugin.options" 
{:style=>:expanded,
 :line_comments=>true,
 :css_location=>"/Users/davide/Code/aggio/public/stylesheets",
 :cache_location=>"/Users/davide/Code/aggio/tmp/sass-cache",
 :template_location=>"/Users/davide/Code/aggio/app/stylesheets",
 :always_update=>false,
 :always_check=>true,
 :full_exception=>true}
```

the main problem is the template location(compass libraries?).
when i import blueprint.sass or other resources exaple fancy buttons, compass doesn't find libraries and return this

File to import not found or unreadable: blueprint.sass

But if i copy blueprint and compass libraries inside /app/stylesheets it works good.
My question is: i need every time to extract libraries from compass gems, or there is a problem with paths?

Comment: Not sure what might be wrong here. Can you show the sass file where you are trying to import blueprint?

Comment: Also, what does Compass.base_directory show from script/console?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Compass 0.10 the problem is probably because the libraries have been converted to the scss syntax and you're calling for "blueprint.sass".

You can reference them without the extension and it should work fine:

```
@import 'blueprint'
```

Also, compass-colors is no longer needed, those functions have been rolled into sass (in the haml gem).

**Update:** It's no longer part of the haml gem, it's a standalone sass gem now.

Comment: you can use this quick search/replace regex in vim: 
:%s/\"/\'/g